# Is it possible to make VNC Viewer send keystrokes regardless of whether mouse pointer is within its window?

Tags: remote-access, vnc-viewer

By default, VNC Viewer (I think it's Tiger VNC; whatever comes by default on Fedora) doesn't send key presses to the remote server if your mouse pointer is not within its window.  This is annoying if you are used to Alt-Tab to whatever window and just type away — VNC makes using mouse necessary even for tasks you normally do from keyboard only.

So, is it possible to make VNC Viewer send keystrokes just when it has focus, regardless of mouse pointer position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Sorry.

I'm used to a slightly dated version of VNC so unless there has been an update which addresses this, no.

You could just use Alt + Tab to select the remote session window before you hit the keys, that is the way I usually get around this.

Hope that helps.